# Не выполняется запрос

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$link) {
        die('<p style="color:red">'.mysqli_connect_errno().' - '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
    }

$rank1 = $_POST['rank1'];
$rank2 = $_POST['rank2'];
$cena = $_POST['paymentamount'];
$steam = $_POST['steam'];
$skype = $_POST['skype'];
$nomerz = rand(10000, 99999);

$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO order_boost (rank1,rank2,cena,steam,skype,nomerz) VALUES ($rank1, $rank2, $cena, $steam, $skype, $nomerz)");

if ($query) {
    echo "Запрос успешно выполнен!";
}
else {
    echo "Ошибка";
}
mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

Но запрос не выполняется, выводиться "ошибка"

Comment: Если говорить русским языком, то у вас написано:
ЕСЛИ rank1 СУЩЕСТВУЕТ, ТО СОЗДАЙ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ $rank1

А вот иначе нет. То есть в случаи если rank1 не существует, переменная $rank1 не будет существовать. Но при этом  в sql выражение вы пытаетесь использовать переменную $rank1 при любых ситуация, даже если она не объявлена

Comment: как решение, объявите переменные до if'ов; $rank1 = $rank2 = $cena = $stream = $skype = '';

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант причины проблемы - пустое значение переданного параметра - уже рассмотрен.

Второй вариант - значения для полей строкового типа не взяты в кавычки.

Попробуйте код в такой форме:

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO order_boost (rank1,rank2,cena,steam,skype,nomerz)
          VALUES ($rank1, $rank2, $cena, $steam, $skype, $nomerz)";
$query = mysqli_query($link, @strSQL);
```

и посмотрите, какой именно текст запроса формируется в переменной. Попробуйте выполнить его с консоли и посмотрите, что скажет сервер. В конце концов, вместо абстрактного

```
echo "Ошибка";
```

выведите то, что вернул сервер.

Comment: Ошибка1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'strSQL' at line 1

Comment: Ну уж могли бы поправить мою опечатку и во втором операторе вместо @strSQL написать $strSQL.

Comment: теперь не выполняется скрипт: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Ну а _какой именно текст запроса формируется в переменной_ - покажете? **UPD:** и заодно _то, что вернул сервер_ - в смысле MySQL-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

POST со значением $rank возможно приходит пустой, а на записи в базу переменные есть все равно. Вот и получается так, пришел пустой POST - значит переменные не объявляем, и соответственно отсюда и ошибка. 
Делайте условие, если POST пришел пустой **$rank = "";**, ну или вообще в базу не заносите, как вам угодно, главное объявить эти переменные в любом случае.

Comment: Так возможно не ввел ничего в эти поля пользователь, и послал форму так. Вы попробуйте убрать запись в базу и просто вывести эти данные, которая посылает форма, чтобы увидеть. echo $_POST['rank'];

Comment: Теперь просто не выполняется запрос.
Без каких либо ошибок.
Ну точнее выполняется echo "Ошибка";, значит запрос не выполняется